# Plot a 3D bar plot from a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

So I Have a list of dictionaries like this

```
[
{
a:floatval,
b:floatval,
c:floatval
},

{
a:floatval,
b:floatval,
c:floatval
}
.......

]
```

I want to plot a 3D bar plot for this distribution.is there any way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share what you have tried so far with us. Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can run a simple loop on this list of dictionary to get 3 lists corresponding to x axis, y axis and z axis.
Find out the number of unique values on x axis, y axis. To populate z axis, make an array of size = no of unique entries on x * no of unique entries on y , now populate this array with the data from your list of dictionaries.
Then you can use matplotlib to plot them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



lst =[{"x":0,"y":1,"z":0.4},{"x":0,"y":0,"z":2.4},{"x":1,"y":1,"z":3.4},{"x":1,"y":0,"z":3.4},{"x":2,"y":0,"z":1.4}]
x_unique=list(set([q["x"] for q in lst]))
y_unique=list(set([q["y"] for q in lst]))
z_data=np.zeros((len(x_unique),len(y_unique)), dtype=float)
for p in lst:
    z_data[p['x']][p['y']]=p['z']


numOfCols = len(x_unique)
numOfRows = len(y_unique)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = "3d")


xpos = np.arange(0, len(x_unique), 1)
ypos = np.arange(0, len(y_unique), 1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos + 0.5, ypos + 0.5)
 
xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(numOfCols * numOfRows)
 
dx = np.ones(numOfRows * numOfCols) * 0.5
dy = np.ones(numOfCols * numOfRows) * 0.5
dz = z_data.flatten()
 
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_unique)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_unique)
 
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
 
plt.show()
```

For another example:
Example: https://coderslegacy.com/python/3d-bar-chart-matplotlib/